# Definition of a non-linear first order Partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Actually I am a little bit confused about the definition. I have read two three articles but I could not find out what type of equations are called a non-linear partial differential equation. Articles are following.

https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equations
https://www.slideshare.net/jayanshugundaniya9/advanced-engineering-mathematics-first-order-nonlinear-partial-differential-equation-its-applications
https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/pde/forth/forth.html

$pq = 0$ will be a first order non linear Partial differential equation? p,q are usual notation in PDE.

Please don' downvote. I know it is a silly question. But I am really confused. Please help me. I am looking forward to ur reply.

Comment: A nonlinear pde is a pde in which the desired function(s) and/or their derivatives have either a power $\neq 1$ or is contained in some nonlinear function like $\exp, \sin$ etc for example, if $\rho:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where three of the inputs are spatial coordinates, then an example of linear: $$\partial_t \rho = \nabla^2\rho$$ and now for nonlinear nonlinear $$partial_t \rho = \nabla^2\rho+ cos\rho$$

Comment: so is my example "$pq = 0$"?

Comment: Can you define specifically what p and q are , Or point me to  specifically which link defines them? I'm unfamiliar with that notation and didn't see it in the links but I may have missed it.

Comment: p is delz bi delx and delz bi delq..I dont know how to write them here.please forgive me for writing like this..If u don't understand , I will find their codes.

Comment: Ahh I see it now. A nonlinear pde is also a pde in which the coordinates are non linear. Example:: $$\partial_t f(x,y,z,t)= \nabla^2 f(x,y,z,t)+xy-yz $$ the $xy$ and $yz$ make it nonlinear. P and q are analogous to x y z and/or t.

Comment: doe means? @user57404

Comment: In your notation, Example:: $$\partial_t f(p,q)= \nabla^2 f(p,q)+pq$$ is nonlinear due to pq

Comment: It was an autocorrect from my phone for "pde" or partial diffferential equation. My apologies.

Comment: Also for dels, you use \Delta. Example:: $$\frac{\Delta{z}}{\Delta{x}}$$

Comment: so apart from having  having greater than one if any differential equation has a nonlinear function of p or q (eg - $sinp$, $sinq$ or $pq$ ,$e^p$), then we will call it a nonlinear pde? Am I right?

Comment: Basically yes. It's a pretty broad definition since anything that isn't linear fits in it. Same way we define nonlinear ordinary differential equations.

Comment: $+(cos0)$...U can write a fresh answer. I would accept it as my answer.

Comment: And note that there exist separate methods for solving either numerically or symbolically for separate kinds of nonlinearity for example , The Cauchy-Euler ODE is nonlinear but we can solve it symbolically. But  this method may not work for other classes of nonlinearity.

Comment: @Shinaolord : Standard usage is $\cos\rho,$ not $cos\rho.$ It is coded as \cos\rho. This differs from \text{cos}\rho in that there is context-dependent spacing, as seen in $2\cos\rho$ and $2\cos(\rho). \qquad$

Comment: Do you know what a linear map is? If $u$ is the unknown function and $L$ an differential operator with $L(u)=v$, then the differential equation $L(u)=v$ i nonlinear, when $L(u_1+u_2)\neq L(u_1)+L(u_2)$ or $L(\lambda u)\neq \lambda L(u)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nonlinear pde is a pde in which  either the desired function(s) and/or their derivatives have either a power $\neq 1$ or is contained in some nonlinear function like $\exp, \sin$ etc, or the coordinates are nonlinear.  for example, if $\rho:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where three of the inputs are spatial coordinates, then an example of linear: $$\partial_t \rho = \nabla^2\rho$$ and now for nonlinear nonlinear $$\partial_t \rho = \nabla^2\rho+ \cos\rho$$

As I stated at the beginning A nonlinear pde can also be a pde in which the coordinates are non linear. Example:: $$\partial_t \rho(x,y,z,t)= \nabla^2 \rho(x,y,z,t)+xy-yz $$ the $xy$ and $yz$ make it nonlinear. P and q are analogous to x y z and/or t. 
$$
\partial_t \rho(x,y,z,t)= \nabla^2 \rho(x,y,z,t)+x^{\frac{13}{21}}$$
Is also nonlinear.

In your notation, Example:: $$\partial_t \rho(p,q)= \nabla^2 \rho(p,q)+pq$$ is nonlinear due to $pq$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for finding geodesics on an arbitrary manifold:
$$\ddot{x}^k=-\Gamma_{ij}^k\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j.$$

Comment: This is not a PDE, this is just an ordinary differential equation (or a system thereof).

Comment: Good point. I can't decide whether to remove it. It is non-linear which I think is the more salient component and the Christoffel symbols are derived using partial derivatives, but in the end, it isn't a PDE.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are functions $F(x,y,z,p,q)$ that are non-linear in $p$ and $q$ and that define a first order partial differential equation via
$$
0=F(x,y,u(x,y),u_x(x,y),u_y(x,y)).
$$
The usual trick is to establish the Lagrange-Charpit equations 
$$
ds=\frac{dx}{F_p}=\frac{dy}{F_q}=\frac{dz}{pF_p+qF_q}=-\frac{dp}{F_x+pF_z}=-\frac{dq}{F_y+qF_z}.
$$
for the characteristic curves and assemble a family of them to form the solution surface $z=u(x,y)$.